# How do I access the Title attribute value of an Input field with Cypress.io?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, cypress

I'm trying to POST to a form with a value that is contained in the title attribute of an input field:

```
<input type="text" id="dynamicStationID" class="stationNameInput" value="Station 1" title="Station 25696" />
```

In the case above, I want to extract the number 25696 from the title attribute and then build my POST as such:

```
cy.request({
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://staging/api/rest/robots.cfm',
form: true,
body: {
  stationName: 'Station 1',
 stationID: '25696' }
```

I can't seem to get my head around how to get that value and plug it into the POST body.

Answer (score 1):

With a little more research, I was able to figure this out:

```
cy.get("input.stationNameInput").then(elem => {
   let score=elem.attr("title").slice(4);
})
```

This gets me the number 25696 that I can use in my POST.